# Dynamically defined Directive is not being compiled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make an extension manager where users can run and test their Angularjs directives.

Users create an `extension` object and pass it to my function where I register the directive.

```
angular.module('CloudBoxes').directive(extension._id, 
    function () {
        return {
            template: extension.html,
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            link: extension.js.controller,
            scope: extension.js.scope
        };
    }
);
```

Test object `extension`

```
{
    _id: "testid",
    js: {
        title: "System.Dir",
        fa: "fa-folder",
        include: ["$http"],
        controller: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            alert("I am ready");
        },
        scope: {
            args: "=",
        }
    },
    html: "<div></div>"
};
```

And I want to test this dynamically added directive using `$compile` on one of my controllers.

```
$scope.$on('startExtension', function (event, id) {
    var el = $compile("<" + id + ">" + "</" + id + ">")($scope);
    $element.append(el);
});
```

`id` argument on `startExtension` event is exactly same with the `extension._id` which I used for dynamically defining directive.

But after $compile, directive is not replaced. On DOM, it is like below

```
<testid class="ng-scope"></testid>
```

Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my fingers! I was going to die trying to find a way for it. But finally found a way to do it!

App.js

```
var providers = {};
angular
    .module('CloudBoxes', [], function ($controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $provide) {
        providers = {
            $controllerProvider: $controllerProvider,
            $compileProvider: $compileProvider,
            $provide: $provide
        };
    });
```

extensionFunction

```
var queueLen = angular.module('CloudBoxes')._invokeQueue.length;
if (extension.js.window) {
    angular.module('CloudBoxes').directive(extension._id, insertArrayAt([
        function () {
            return {
                template: extension.html,
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                link: extension.js.controller,
                scope: extension.js.scope
            };
        }
    ], 0, extension.js.include));
    var queue = angular.module('CloudBoxes')._invokeQueue;
    for (var i = queueLen; i < queue.length; i++) {
        var call = queue[i];
        var provider = providers[call[0]];
        if (provider) {
            provider[call[1]].apply(provider, call[2]);
        }
    }
    setBindings(extension);
} else {
    setBindings(extension);
}
```

Thanks to person who created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MzseV/7/)!

Answer (score 0):

Once the AngularJS application is bootstrapped, an injector is created with everything that was registered at that time. Registering a new component does not add it to the injector, so `$compile` does not see it.

One way to do this would be to create a second AngularJS application that is re-created each time a new component needs to be added. You will want to create this in DOM that is separate from your primary application to prevent conflicts between the two (possibly in an iframe).